# Second Derivative with respect to a Matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, fisher-information

I have a question regarding (second order) derivative with respect to a matrix. I encounter this question because I am calculating Fisher Information, but I guess the context is not very relevant in this question.

Here is the derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma} \Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}
$$

where $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix (positive semi-definite, symmetric), and $A = (x_i - \mu_0)(x_i -\mu_o)^T$, but we may simply use $A$ instead while knowing $A$ is symmetric.

Before posting this question, I have searched on google, and found several sources useful and relevant, but do not answer my question straightaway:

1. https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf
2. [Second order derivative of the inverse matrix operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903677/second-order-derivative-of-the-inverse-matrix-operator)

Consequently, I have made a coarse attempt to derive it, but I am not confident whether it is correct.

====================================================================

Consider a very small $\delta\Sigma$

\begin{align*}
(\Sigma + \delta\Sigma)^{-1}A(\Sigma+\delta\Sigma)^{-1} &= [\Sigma(I+\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma))]^{-1}A[(I+(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1})\Sigma]^{-1}\\
&=(I+\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma))^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(I+(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}\\
&=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n[\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)]^n)\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n[(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}]^n)\\
&\approx (I-\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma))\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(I-(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1})\\
&=\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}\\
+\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}
\end{align*}

Then, we may have

\begin{align*}
(\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma} \Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1})\delta\Sigma &= \lim_{||\delta\Sigma||\rightarrow0}(\Sigma + \delta\Sigma)^{-1}A(\Sigma+\delta\Sigma)^{-1} - \Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}\\
&\approx \lim_{||\delta\Sigma||\rightarrow0}- \Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}(\delta\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}
\end{align*}

(somehow by magic or by speculating, I guess)
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma} \Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1} = - \Sigma^{-2}A\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-2}
$$

====================================================================

I have a feeling that I may be around there, but not quite yet. I am really hoping to get from this question the output of the derivative.

Thank you so much for all of your time!

p.s.:

1. You do not have to follow my trail of thoughts (which could be wrong per se), and you may just show the correct way of doing this.
2. I call this second order derivative because $\Sigma^{-1}A\Sigma^{-1}$ is what I have obtained by taking first derivative of $(x_i-\mu_0)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu_0)$, and yes, all you smart people may have realized this is multivariate normal.

====================================================================

In a month after I posted this question, I managed to find a great reference I would like to share. For those people who are having similar questions, here is a book that will give you a great insight (which closely resembles the method presented by @greg).

"Matrix Differential Calculus with applications in statistics" by Magnus and Neudecker.

Take a look at its Chapter 2, which offers great explanations (and examples) about kronecker product and vector operation, two important concepts when dealing with matrix differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ease of typing let's use the notations
$$\eqalign{
 X &= \Sigma \cr
A:X &= {\rm \,tr\,}(A^TX) \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{\{trace/Frobenius product\}} \cr
}$$

Now we can write the original scalar function and find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= A:X^{-1} \cr
d\phi &= A:dX^{-1} = -A:X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} = -X^{-1}AX^{-1}:dX \cr
G=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= -X^{-1}AX^{-1} \cr
}$$
To proceed to the Hessian, let's introduce the 4th order tensor ${\mathcal H}$ with components
$$\eqalign{
{\mathcal H}_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jl} \cr
}$$
Now we can calculate the differential and gradient of $G$ as
$$\eqalign{
dG
 &= -dX^{-1}\,AX^{-1} -X^{-1}A\,dX^{-1} \cr
 &= X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}AX^{-1} + X^{-1}AX^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1} \cr
 &= -(X^{-1}\,dX\,G + G\,dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
 &= -(X^{-1}{\mathcal H}G + G{\mathcal H}X^{-1}):dX \cr
\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial X^2} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial X} &= -(X^{-1}{\mathcal H}G + G{\mathcal H}X^{-1}) \cr\cr
}$$
If you are not comfortable with higher-order tensors, you can use vectorization instead
$$\eqalign{
  {\rm vec}(dG) &= -{\rm vec}(X^{-1}\,dX\,G + G\,dX\,X^{-1}) \cr
  dg &= -(G\otimes X^{-1} + X^{-1}\otimes G)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} &= -(G\otimes X^{-1} + X^{-1}\otimes G) \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:** In some of these steps, I made use of the fact that $(X,A,G)$ are symmetric matrices.

Comment: It is such a great answer. Thank you! Nevertheless, I have some questions, which I would appreciate if you could elaborate further. 1. why $dX^{-1}=-X^{-1}dXX^{-1}$ instead of, say, $-X^{-2}dX$? 2. why $d\phi = -tr(X^{-1}AX^{-1}dX)$ implies $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} = -X^{-1}AX^{-1}$? Why can I take $dX$ out? 3. I could be wrong, but do you suggest my coarse attempt somehow magically led me to the correct answer? Thank you again for your time!

Comment: 1) Start with the equation $I=XX^{-1}$, take its differential, then isolate $dX^{-1}$ on the LHS $$\eqalign{0&=dX\,X^{-1}+X\,dX^{-1}\cr dX^{-1}&=-X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}}$$ 2) A matrix gradient is defined such that $$d\phi=G:dX\implies\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X}=G$$ 3) I don't believe in magic!$\,\,$